# Which attribute is used for SwitchPreference color?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'd like to adjust the colors in my settings fragment switches with styles.

The on position colors are done with `<item name="colorAccent">@color/light_main_3</item>`.
I managed to change the color of the bar in the back in the off position with `<item name="android:colorForeground">@color/dark_text_secondary</item>`.

The only thing I haven't manage to change is the **circle** in it's **off** position.
Which attribute is used for that?

[Change white circle (off position)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBNyj.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change switch color when disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36428557/change-switch-color-when-disabled)

Comment: @Sekiro, `"colorSwitchThumbNormal"` had no effect on my switch. `"colorControlActivated"` changes the checked color (Overrides `"colorAccent"`, only for switchable components).

I do not intent to disable the switchpreference, only check and uncheck.
It is the unchecked color which is still not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

`<item name="android:colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/dark_text_secondary</item>`

in your activity `Theme`. It is working for me.